# Why do we need the absolute value signs when integrating the square of a function?

Tags: integration, notation, lp-spaces

Why do we need the absolute value signs in the definition of [square-integrable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function)? As seen below:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 \, dx < \infty $$

Comment: The absolute value signs ensure that the integrand is a non-negative real function.

Comment: The other answers are right, but I'll add that it also looks best (to me) among the options $$\int (f(x))^2\,dx\quad \int |f(x)|^2\,dx\quad \int f(x)^2\,dx\quad \int f^2(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because complex-valued functions are used.  The square of a complex number need not be non-negative.

Comment: Why do it need to be non-negative? Just simply a subtraction on the integration, I think.

Comment: Because one is trying to define a metric with properties similar to those of the metric in Euclidean space.

Answer (score 16):

Besides the complex-valued case, I suspect it also has to do with the existence of other $L^p$ spaces; [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces) gives the general definition as

$$
\|f\|_p = \left(\int_S |f|^p \,d\mu\right)^{1/p}
$$

Since the absolute value symbols are redundant only for even integral $p$, omitting them disrupts the uniformity of the notation without buying a whole lot.

Comment: In other words, tradition?

Comment: @BCLC: not really. Tradition would be "we write it that way because we always have". Which might be *true*, but it's not an alternative way of phrasing this explanation, which is "we write it that way because we consider $2$ to be a special case of $p$, and it would be weird to write the special case differently".