# What are some terms to distinguish algebra over a field vs algebra over a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules, terminology

For an $F$-module $V$, if $F$ turns out to be a field, then $V$ is called a(n $F$-)vector space. Thus, we have the special term vector space for modules over fields.

(Btw, the ring $F$ maybe unital, commutative, [associative](https://mathematicsgre.com/viewtopic.php?t=4583#p19456), whatever you want. And then if $F$ is a unital ring, then $V$ may or may not be a unital module. Up to you.)

1. Is there any particular term for $G$-algebra $A$ where $G$ is some ring, when $G$ turns out to be a field? All I found is [algebra over a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) and [algebra over a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Generalization:_algebra_over_a_ring). (Again: $G$ is whatever kind of ring you want. And then $A$ is whatever kind of $G$-module you want)
2. If no, then is there any particular reason besides [tradition or whatever](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/907383) why we have (more of) a distinction of modules over rings vs modules over fields as compared to algebras over rings vs algebras over fields? Perhaps vector spaces have far more properties than modules as compared to field-algebras over ring-algebras?

Comment: Your question is why we have special terminology of modules and vector spaces, but not $R$-algebras and $K$-algebras?

Comment: @mizh thanks for commenting. yes, assuming your $R$ is ring, and your $K$ is field. and indeed the terminology is 'algebra over a field' and 'algebra over a ring', but that's lame. in this case, we might as well say 'module over $\mathbb R$'.

Comment: And besides, there's a lot of terminology that's lame, but arguably referring to $K$ and $R$-algebras gets the point across better than calling them $K$-algebras and $R$-<something else?>, especially when their definitions are essentially the same.

Comment: The same isn't true when distinguishing modules and rings - many properties about vector spaces no longer hold when considering modules, and modules generalise to many other areas of algebra and mathematics as well.

Comment: We can use '**vector algebra**' to emphasize that it's a vector space (i.e. the ring is a field).

Comment: @mizh thanks for commenting. 1 -  'when their definitions are essentially the same' - oh yeah i was thinking that. i edited post. so not much additional info for field-algebras as compared to ring-algebras apart from that field-algebras are vector spaces while ring-algebras are modules? 2 - 'distinguishing modules and rings ' --> did you mean modules and vector spaces? 3 - 'An algebra has much more structure than a module.' --> what's the relevance of this please?

Comment: @Berci thanks. but [eh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra). XD

Comment: Yes, an $R$-algebra is (by definition) always an $R$-module, but obviously not vice versa. Yes, I meant distinguishing modules vs. vector spaces.

Comment: @mizh you answered the 2nd and 3rd follow-ups but not the 1st follow-up? re 3rd follow up: but what's the relevance? I know modules are not necessarily algebras

Comment: I put it in an answer because I felt it would be better contained there.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question comment.

An algebra over a field is simply an algebra over a ring where the ring is a field. Not much is 'lost' in this translation - everything you expect to hold for an associative algebra will also hold if you replace it with a field. On the other hand, a vector space is a module over a field, but these are vastly different topics - for example, a module doesn't always have a basis, let alone have the concept of 'linear independence'. e.g. elements of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ prime are never 'linearly independent'.

Comment: @mizh 'everything you expect to hold for an associative algebra will also hold if you replace it with a field' - except for the vector space vs module thing but then this is pretty much the only (or actually the only?) difference?

Comment: What do you mean by your previous question? I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @mizh  'everything you expect to hold for an associative algebra will also hold if you replace it with a field' - This is how I understand: For $F-$algebra $V_F$ vs $G-$algebra $V_G$, the only difference here is that $V_F$ is a vector space while $V_G$ is a vector space. Since this difference is already encapsulated by the different terms 'vector space' and 'module', there is no further need to distinguish that $V_F$ is a field-algebra while $V_G$ is a ring-algebra. --> is this right?